# How change Height of iframe dynamicly when different pages loaded in it , by javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, height

I want a JavaScript code that change iframe height as well as the iframe's content's height is changed.

I don't want to calculate the height just when the main page has loaded, the iframe content has some elements loaded with Ajax and changes without refreshing the whole page, therefore the height of content changes dynamically without reloading. I want some way to dynamically calculate the height of iframe's contents and change the height attribute of iframe itself.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is iframe from the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

The code should look something like this:

```
function resizeFrame(f) {
    f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + “px”;
}
```

You can find an example to this URL:

http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/iframe-height-scrollbar-example/

Comment: It has to be mentioned that the approach will work only if main window and frame are from same domain. Otherwise, you won't be able to access `document` property on it.

Comment: Thanks, No The IFrame is from another domain . so i cant calculate the size of other domain :(